# Refreshing a Variable multiple times a frame(for a texture array in a shader)

Tags: c++, shader, textures, vulkan

I want to Update an integer multiple times in frame so that the fragment-shader can access the right index of a texture array for different objects.
I first tried it with a PushConstant but this doesn´t work because it can only be changed one time per record of the commandbuffer.

So it would be very kind if somebody could tell me how to do this or if i should change the process of getting the right textures for an object in a different way.

Comment: You could use uniform buffers. However, why don't you just record multiple draws into the same command buffer with different push constants? This is most likely more efficient too than submitting the same command buffer multiple times.

Comment: 1. I wanted to try out uniform buffers but i suspected that they may not be synchronized with the drawcalls (but i dont really know if that is the case), but i will still try it out. 2. I am currently recording the drawcalls in the same command buffer but (and i hope that i understand your comment right) i want to have i kind of "dynamic". What i mean with this is that i don´t want to specify all of the different pushconstants in the shader(and so on) when i change the number of objects. I want it to be automatically changable by my application.

Comment: You'll need one entry per draw call in the uniform buffer. Also, why would you need to specify "all the different push constants" in the shader when you change the number of objects? Setting push constants gets recorded into the command buffer too. So, when recording the buffer, you first set the push constants, then issue a draw call, then set the same push constants to a different value, issue another draw call... You can change the values of push constants as often as you want. They're exactly what you need.

Comment: "*because it can only be changed one time per record of the commandbuffer.*" This is incorrect. You can change it as often as you want within a CB.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! I´ve solved the issue, which was that I was using the vertex- and indexBufferOffsets wrong.